# AJAX HTML breaks Divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using AJAX and HTML to pull a name from a **POST** request, and then returning the data to fill a div with the response.

The **data** returns, but for some reason it breaks the `div` and adds a **New Line** to the equation, making the page look unprofessional.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function getSummary(id)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://localhost/notyouraveragebear',
     data: "username="+id, 
     success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("personname").innerText=data;

     }

   });

}
getSummary(1234);
</script>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>ArchServers Control Panel</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">ArchServers Control Panel</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu message-dropdown">
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-footer">
                            <a href="#">Read All New Messages</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-default">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-primary">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-success">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-info">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-warning">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-danger">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">View All</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <div id = "personname"><p></p></div> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Charts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bootstrap-elements.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i> Bootstrap Elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bootstrap-grid.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Bootstrap Grid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Dropdown <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index-rtl.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> RTL Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Dashboard <small>Statistics Overview</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>  <strong>Like SB Admin?</strong> Try out <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2" class="alert-link">SB Admin 2</a> for additional features!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">26</div>
                                        <div>New Comments!</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-green">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">12</div>
                                        <div>New Tasks!</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">124</div>
                                        <div>New Orders!</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-red">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-support fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">13</div>
                                        <div>Support Tickets!</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Area Chart</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> Donut Chart</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="#">View Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Tasks Panel</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="list-group">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">just now</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> Calendar updated
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">4 minutes ago</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i> Commented on a post
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">23 minutes ago</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-truck"></i> Order 392 shipped
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">46 minutes ago</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-money"></i> Invoice 653 has been paid
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">1 hour ago</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> A new user has been added
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">2 hours ago</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Completed task: "pick up dry cleaning"
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">yesterday</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-globe"></i> Saved the world
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                        <span class="badge">two days ago</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Completed task: "fix error on sales page"
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="#">View All Activity <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Transactions Panel</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Order #</th>
                                                <th>Order Date</th>
                                                <th>Order Time</th>
                                                <th>Amount (USD)</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3326</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>3:29 PM</td>
                                                <td>$321.33</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3325</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>3:20 PM</td>
                                                <td>$234.34</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3324</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>3:03 PM</td>
                                                <td>$724.17</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3323</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>3:00 PM</td>
                                                <td>$23.71</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3322</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>2:49 PM</td>
                                                <td>$8345.23</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3321</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>2:23 PM</td>
                                                <td>$245.12</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3320</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>2:15 PM</td>
                                                <td>$5663.54</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3319</td>
                                                <td>10/21/2013</td>
                                                <td>2:13 PM</td>
                                                <td>$943.45</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="#">View All Transactions <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

When i remove the div id personname, and insert just text there, such as my name Christopher, the content on the page appears correctly, without new lines.

As soon as I request the data and its returned and changed with the .textContent, the page adds line breaks and the page looks silly.

Any advice on this?

Here is the page with the replaced content.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3SBp.jpg

Here is the page with static content.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev05s.jpg

here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('HTTPD Server Started');
});

app.post('/notyouraveragebear', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Christopher');
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: is `data` html or pure text?

Comment: pure text. for example it will just respond with Christopher

Comment: Share your backend code, the issue could be there. Or try setting the data with jQuery (.html() or .text())

Comment: If you are sure the respond will be just plain text, have you tried to substitute that `data` variable with the string "Christopher" to see if it also adds a new line? That way you will be 100% sure the problem is not in the JavaScript but in the backend. `document.getElementById("personname").textContent="Christopher";`

Comment: After changing my textcontent to "Christopher" inline code, the page has the same effect of being with a newline.

Comment: Is very strange because I have tested that code and it doesn't add a new line for me. https://jsfiddle.net/nabx2twj/
Inspect the element and you will see there is no newline inside the `div` element with `id` personname.

Comment: Try innerText. See: https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

Comment: Using innerText provided no change, Its worth mentioning that this is inside of a dropdown. I wonder if it might be external? Possibly in the dropdown?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but i posted the entire code instead of just that snippet.

Comment: It seems to be a CSS problem.